# Replace free function native callback with member function using boost::bind

Tags: c++, windows, boost, callback, c++-cli

I have native C++ classes wrapped by C++/CLI classes so that C# classes can use them. Nasty, but works. So far, to map native callbacks to .NET events I did things like this in my wrapper classes:

```
void Wrapper::ManagedEvent::add( Action^ managedEventHandler ){
    m_dManagedEvent += managedEventHandler;
    m_pNativeInstance->registerEventCallback( static_cast<INativeInterface::NativeCallback*>(
        Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate( managedEventHandler ).ToPointer() ) );
}

void Wrapper::ManagedEvent::remove( Action^ managedEventHandler ){
    m_dManagedEvent -= managedEventHandler;
    m_pNativeInstance->registerEventCallback( NULL );
}
```

- `m_dManagedEvent` is a `System::Action^`
- Native callbacks are defined as free functions; in this case, `typedef void __stdcall NativeCallback();`, inside `INativeInterface`.

This works fine, but now I fell in love with Boost, that means using `boost::function` and `boost::bind`. That works great between native classes, but let's say I want to change my
`registerEventCallback` function so that it receives a `boost::function<void()>`. How would I have to change the `add` and `remove` methods?

I thought of this, but it forces me to write another member function per event, and I'm not sure it would even build because `this` is a tracking handle:

```
void Wrapper::FireManagedEvent(){
    m_dManagedEvent();
}

void Wrapper::ManagedEvent::add( Action^ managedEventHandler ){
        m_dManagedEvent += managedEventHandler;
        m_pNativeInstance->registerEventCallback( boost::bind( &Wrapper::FireManagedEvent, this ) );
    }
```

Is there a better solution?

**Update**: Per @Ben Voigt's answer, I tried the following:

```
   void Wrapper::ManagedEvent::add( Action^ managedEventHandler ){
        m_dManagedEvent += managedEventHandler;
        m_pNativeInstance->registerEventCallback( static_cast< boost::function< void() > >(
            Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate( managedEventHandler ).ToPointer() ) );
    }
```

But it gives a compiler error:

```
2>D:\SVN.DRA.WorkingCopy\DRALibraries\Boost_1_48_0\boost/function/function_template.hpp(112): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
2>          D:\SVN.DRA.WorkingCopy\DRALibraries\Boost_1_48_0\boost/function/function_template.hpp(110) : while compiling class template member function 'void boost::detail::function::void_function_invoker0<FunctionPtr,R>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer &)'
2>          with
2>          [
2>              FunctionPtr=void *,
2>              R=void
2>          ]
2>          D:\SVN.DRA.WorkingCopy\DRALibraries\Boost_1_48_0\boost/function/function_template.hpp(907) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::detail::function::void_function_invoker0<FunctionPtr,R>' being compiled
2>          with
2>          [
2>              FunctionPtr=void *,
2>              R=void
2>          ]
2>          D:\SVN.DRA.WorkingCopy\DRALibraries\Boost_1_48_0\boost/function/function_template.hpp(722) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::function0<R>::assign_to<Functor>(Functor)' being compiled
2>          with
2>          [
2>              R=void,
2>              Functor=void *
2>          ]
2>          D:\SVN.DRA.WorkingCopy\DRALibraries\Boost_1_48_0\boost/function/function_template.hpp(1043) : see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::function0<R>::function0<void*>(Functor,int)' being compiled
2>          with
2>          [
2>              R=void,
2>              Functor=void *
2>          ]
2>          Test.cpp(61) : see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::function<Signature>::function<void*>(Functor,int)' being compiled
2>          with
2>          [
2>              Signature=void (void),
2>              Functor=void *
2>          ]
2>
2>Build FAILED.
```

(Line 61 of Test.cpp is the last one of the `add` method)

**Update 2**: Doing this, it builds and runs OK:

```
void Wrapper::ManagedEvent::add( Action^ managedEventHandler ){
    m_dManagedEvent += managedEventHandler;
    void(__stdcall*pTrampoline)() = static_cast<void(__stdcall*)()>( Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate( managedEventHandler ).ToPointer() );
    m_pNativeInstance->registerEventCallback( boost::function<void()>(pTrampoline) );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  What you already have.

`GetFunctionPointerForDelegate` creates a trampoline containing the `this` pointer, so there's no need for `boost::bind`.

The only thing that will change is instead of passing a plain function pointer, you'll pass a `boost::function` functor.  The conversion should be implicit, your C++/CLI code won't need to change.

Besides, before you fall too much in love with Boost, look at the `std::function` class, it has many new capabilities with C++11.

Comment: It doesn't compile, see my updated question. I also tried `reinterpret_cast` and got a different error.

Comment: I fixed it, seems like a calling convention thing: it seems like C++/CLI uses __cdecl by default, and an explicit cast involving __stdcall is necessary. See the last update to the question. Now it compiles, and works correctly. Please tell me if there is a more elegant way, or some pitfall I'm not noticing.

Comment: @dario: I'm not sure, but I think you need to use `__cdecl` to be compatible with `std::function` and `boost::function`.  You can make `GetFunctionPointerForDelegate` return a `void(__cdecl*)()` by specifying `CallingConvention::Cdecl` on the managed delegate type.